# Convert Context-Free Grammar to Automata

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I am trying to convert the following grammar to an automata:

Let $S$ be the start symbol.

1. $S \to aQc$
2. $Q \to aQc$
3. $Q \to aaRbb$
4. $R \to aaRbb$
5. $R \to \epsilon$.

But I don't fully understand how to convert these types of grammar. Is there some steps I can follow in understanding the process?

How do I go about converting this grammar to an automata?

Comment: You can find lots of stuff on the web about converting a context-free grammar to a pushdown automaton.

Comment: @saulspatz Those what I have found I don't fully understand.

Comment: Can you explain where you are having difficulty?  How far can you get with this problem?  Where are you getting stuck?  Otherwise, I don't see what anyone can do but re-create a presentation you say you can't understand.

Comment: @saulspatz Mos of what I've seen says that for example, with $aaRbb$ you put each character into the pile including the state, did I understand that correctly? Then when I remove a state I replace with the respective production?

Comment: @saulspatz Mos of what I've seen says that for example, with $aaRbb$ you put each character into the pile including the state, did I understand that correctly? Then when I remove a state I replace with the respective production?

Comment: By "pile" do you mean "stack?"  By "state" do you mean "nonterminal symbol?" There's more than one formalism, but basically the idea is that either you match a terminal symbol, that is if the the symbol at the top of stack is a terminal, and that is also the first symbol on the input tape, you can remove it from both the input and the stack, or if the symbol at the top of stack is a nonterminal, you can pop off the stack it and replace it by the string on the right-hand side of any one of its productions.

Answer (score 0):

showing that every grammar has a matching PDA is actually very simple by constructing a PDA that nonderministically goes through all the possible productions of the grammar.

Given G = (V,T,P,S), define M = ({q},T,TUV,δ,q,S,{}) (notice only one state is needed).

Define δ:

For each variable A in V, δ(q, ε, A) = {(q, α)|A → α is a production of P }.

For each terminal a in T, δ(q, a, a) = {(q, ε)}.

With this, your problem is solved.

This is the standard construction shown when proving one direction of the equivalence of PDA’s and CGF’s, so finding more info should be very easy.